# Scatter plot with multiple markers

Tags: matlab, markers, scatter-plot

I am trying to put a scatter plot together from multiple data files, to see how the correlate to each other. The code looks like this:

```
hold all
fia = fopen('data.txt');
A = fscanf(fia, '%f %f %f', [3 inf]);
t = A(1,:);
a = A(2,:);
r = A(3,:);

figure(1)
scatter(log(r),log(a),'r', '-');

fclose(fia);

fia = fopen('data.txt');
A = fscanf(fia, '%f %f %f', [3 inf]);
t = A(1,:);
a = A(2,:);
r = A(3,:);

figure(2);
scatter(log(r),log(a), 'g', '-');

fclose(fia);
```

And so on, where the next data points are plotted on the same graph:

```
fia = fopen('data.txt');
A = fscanf(fia, '%f %f %f', [3 inf]);
t = A(1,:);
a = A(2,:);
r = A(3,:);

figure(1);
scatter(log(r),log(a), 'rx');


fclose(fia);
```

ect.

But when I run the function in Matlab, I get this error:

```
Error using specgraph.scattergroup/set
The name 'linestyle' is not an accessible property for an instance
of class 'scattergroup'.

Error in specgraph.scattergroup (line 26)
  set(h,args{:});

Error in scatter (line 83)
        h = specgraph.scattergroup('parent',parax,'cdata',c,...

Error in Ratioincrease (line 11)
scatter(log(r),log(a),'r', '-');
```

How can I have the scattergroup similar to a line group, as in how do I write it properly?

Comment: '-' is a linestyle property. It's meaningless on a scatter plot. What are you trying to do with it? Do you want the scatter markers to be minus signs? That isn't possible. Check `doc linespec` under "Marker Specifics" as to what markers you can use.

Answer (score 7):

There shouldn't be a problem to use `scatter` and show different markers. For example:

```
load seamount
scatter(x,y,30,z,'s'); hold on
scatter(.999*x,1.001*y,30,z,'x'); hold on
scatter(1.001*x,.999*y,30,z,'+'); hold on
```

[image]

I suspect that you had a typo and used `-` as a marker type. The marker types you can use are :

- `'+'`    Plus sign
- `'o'`     Circle
- `'*'`    Asterisk
- `'.'`    Point
- `'x'`    Cross
- `'square'` or `'s'`  Square
- `'diamond'` or `'d'` Diamond
- `'^'`    Upward-pointing triangle
- `'v'`    Downward-pointing triangle
- `'>'`    Right-pointing triangle
- `'<'`    Left-pointing triangle
- `'pentagram'` or `'p'` Five-pointed star (pentagram)
- `'hexagram'` or `'h'`  Six-pointed star (hexagram)

Comment: if i have x vector and y vector and i make a scatter plot. how do i give different colours to x and y values

Comment: each point has a [x,y] coordinate from that x,y vector, you plot a set of points defined by these vectors. how do you define these specific x,y points in that vector?

Answer (score 2):

Just to add that you don't have to write 'hold on' for each line. Once will be sufficient.
So, for this you can write:

```
load seamount
scatter(x,y,30,z,'s'); hold on
scatter(.999*x,1.001*y,30,z,'x'); 
scatter(1.001*x,.999*y,30,z,'+');
```

Also, if you wanna draw a new set of data and clean the previous, you need to write 'hold off'  once before doing this command.

Answer (score -2):

The scattergroup property name is 'marker'

Check in doc 'Scattergroup Properties'